# Using ArcGIS ModelBuilder to perform In-line variable substitution for input data path?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

Does anyone know how/if you can use in-line variable substitution for an input path name in ModelBuilder for ArcGIS 10?

I used "get field value" to retrieve a code from one feature class, and I want to substitute that text string in two places in another input variable pathname.

For instance, if I used "get field value" to retrieve the code "ABC123", I would use that to call up a raster (make raster layer) with this path name: "D:\Data\Rasters\%ABC123%\el_%ABC123%

Does anyone know if this will work?

ModelBuilder won't recognize this as a valid path name right now.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do this in Model builder, though it sure would be useful. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/480/compound-variables-in-model-builder. It was written when I was using arcgis 9.3, maybe v10 is different. You can do this in python though.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this using the **Calculate Value** tool, see [Adding arbitrary code to ArcGIS ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25584/add-arbitrary-code-to-arcgis-model-builder)

Answer (score -1):

You need quotes.

`D:\Data\Rasters\%ABC123%\el_%ABC123%`

should be

`D:\Data\Rasters\'%ABC123%'\el_'%ABC123%'`