# Using variable from arcpy.GetParameterAsText() as part of output path?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, parameters

I´m trying to use a variable as part of the output path of a shutil command.
Unfortunately I couldn´t work it out how to do it. Can anybody help?

```
import arcpy
import shutil
Name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
shutil.copyfile("C:\\test.txt", "C:\\%Name%.txt")
```

This question here is similar, but was never answered:
[Using ArcGIS ModelBuilder to perform In-line variable substitution for input data path?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14149/arcgis-10-model-builder-in-line-variable-substitution-for-input-data-path)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```python
import arcpy
import shutil


outbasename=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#outfilename=r"C:\" + outbasename + ".txt"  # Original with typo
outfilename = "C:\\" + str(outbasename) + ".txt"
shutil.copyfile("C:\\test.txt",outfilename)
```

this is how I would do it in arcpy in a script tool

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I´m getting an error message: <type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:\\" + outbasename.txt'

Comment: that's what i get for trying to code on a machine without python

Comment: You may not have permission to write to that location. IOError usually occur when Python has trouble completing a task that requires writing to the disk.

Comment: I´m trying to run the script from ArcGIS 10 with Python 2.6. It´s my computer and I´m administrator, so writing permissions shouldn´t be the problem. Any other idea ?

Comment: \" escapes the second ". You will need to replace the line with this text.... `outfilename = "C:\\" + str(outbasename) + ".txt"`

Comment: An alternative is to use string substitution. `outfilename="C:\\%s.txt" % (outbasename)` The `%s` means that a string is substituted at that location from the tuple that follows (in this case containing only the variable outbasename, which will be coerced to a string).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) namespace for common pathname manipulations. I would also parameterize the input file and output locations instead of hardcoding them but of course that's up to you.

I would do something like this:

```
import arcpy, os, shutil
inputfile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
ext = os.path.splitext(inputfile)[1] # returns file extension, e.g. ".txt"
outbasename = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
outfilename = os.path.join(outfolder, outbasename + ext)
shutil.copyfile(inputfile, outfilename)
```